# bold header text for rails and html

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails

i want to make create an account button to be bold as the login button.
The create an account button is made like this:

```
<%= f.submit "Create an account", class: "btn-submit" %>
```

With additional CSS:

```
.btn-submit {
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
background: #c91717;
padding: 11px 20px;
border: 0;
margin-top: 6px;
}
```

And the Log In button is already bold link-to like:

```
<%= link_to("Register", {:controller => 'users', :action => 'new'}, :class => 'tosignup') %>
```

The CSS for this:

```
.tologin {

color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 18px;
text-transform: uppercase;
text-decoration: none;
background: #c91717;
padding: 11px 20px;
border: 0;
margin-top: 6px;
margin-left: 905px;
}
```

I don't know how to make the Create and Account button to be bold as the login link-to button is? Can you help me out? Thank you

Comment: try to find out what class adds it using the inspect element tool in your browser. It doesn't look like its the .tologin class

Comment: You should probably answer your question with your answer so future people who visit this question can see the solution with ease.

Answer (score 0):

The Element tool helped me! I've deleted in the general html and body brackets the font-weight: bold. And now the login link-to is like the create an account unbolded. Thank you